# are cookies secure from hijacking over http

Tags: http, cookies, https

I see facebook sends cookies over http. How are they secure from hijacking? If I were to copy the cookie onto another computer would I be logged in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've just described Session Hijacking, and it is a real security issue. It can be avoided in a number of [ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking). The simplest way to secure the cookies, though, is to ensure they're encrypted over the wire by using HTTPS rather than HTTP.

Comment: but when the cookies get to the box, they are unencrypted right?  So as the OP said, could he just copy the cookie to another machine?

Comment: Yep, that's why I said "simplest". However, my argument there is that if someone already has physical access to a logged-in machine, they don't need the cookie. In general, if physical security has been compromised (i.e. workstation password, or even outer-door locks) cookies will never be secure, so you might as well plan so that other (and I would argue much more common) cases are handled.

Comment: i was just seeking clarification, if someone just grabbed the cookie, they could use it to log in with another browser, right?  Or no?  I think yes (otherwise getting the cookie would have limited utility), but just want to be clear.

Comment: Assuming that the site used only the cookie for authentication (and not a multi-factor scheme that could also include IP address, user-agent request header, etc.) then you're right: another browser, even on a different machine, could "log in" using the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies sent over HTTP (port 80) are not secure as the HTTP protocol is not encrypted.

Cookies sent over HTTPS (port 443) are secure as HTTPS is encrypted.

So, if Facebook sends/receives cookies via HTTP, they can be stolen and used nefariously.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies sent over HTTP are unsecure, those sent over HTTPS are a bit more secure than HTTP, however they can still be stolen since there are a few methods discovered lately to hack SSL. A complete writeup on session hijacking and all of the session hijacking attacks can be found here: http://cleverlogic.net/tutorials/session-hijacking-0. There is also a bit on preventing Session Hijacking.